# Making a logo transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

Logo I'm working with is a drawing of hands holding a heart. Drawing is open at the wrists, so cutting it out is not an option.  How can I make the logo itself (which is red and white) show, and the background transparent--as if it was printed on clear plastic?I have some jpeg files, and I want to be able to use this in word as well as CS6.  I do not have the original artwork.

Comment: What application are you using?? "CS6" includes more than 20 applications.

Comment: I've tried it in Illustrator and In Photoshop

Comment: For jpgs you should use Photoshop. There are a number of questions here already covering background removal: [CLICK HERE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+background+photoshop)

Answer (score 0):

Some programs allow to set the transparency of an image after importing (InDesign, Illstrator, ...) - this is the easy way.

If your software does not, try this:
Open in Photoshop, double click on the Background-Layer (to make it a 'normal' layer), set the transparency and save it as .png file. JPG does not support transparency.

Comment: When I do that--lower the opacity to, say 50%--the entire logo goes gray--I don't just lose the white background, I lose the whole thing.

Comment: I think I got your question wrong. Go with Scott's comment to your question.